# Continious location updates even if app is terminated in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cllocationmanager

can anybody help me with getting device location even when the app is terminated.
I know how to get location when app is in background.
But I am still not able to get it when app is closed/terminated by user.

Thanks,
Nilesh

Comment: could you please tell me how to get location when app is in background?
as you told in your question.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kindly refer 
http://mobileoop.com/getting-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-when-the-app-is-killedterminatedsuspended
I have not tested the same. But you can give a try.

Answer (score 1):

kindly refer to these pages. it can be done using

`[[LocationController sharedInstance] startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];`

1) [recieving location updates after app is terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977679/recieving-location-updates-after-app-is-terminated)

2.) [iOS update location even when app is terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788865/ios-update-location-even-when-app-is-terminated)

3.) http://mobileoop.com/getting-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-when-the-app-is-killedterminatedsuspended

Answer (score -1):

Once application got terminated from background, There is no way to retrieve the location continuously.