# Open iOS app automatically at a certain time

Tags: ios

Is this possible? Like the app will launch at 8AM and closes at 10PM. I'm new to developing an app that uses background. What I do know currently is that the app can run in the background for a long time.

What I also have right now is my project that updates the user location in the background. With the help of this https://github.com/silento/Location - re-written in Swift 3.0.

Comment: Do you want to run your app always in ___Background___ mode?

Comment: Use notifications. But app must run in background.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Yes, the app has only two screens. So, conclusion is: use local notifications to ask user to turn on the app. Cool.

Comment: you can update user location even your app in suspended as well.

Comment: @matloobHasnain how to do that? Can you provide me any tutorial or working piece of code?

Comment: @matloobHasnain no way???

Comment: let me give you a link I was reading last day

Comment: https://github.com/voyage11/GettingLocationWhenSuspended

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749476/ios-9-how-get-locations-even-if-app-terminated

Comment: read above links please

Comment: i cant test it properly if you test please let me know its status , but peoples are saying that its works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. But, you can use local notifications to tell user to run the app.

Comment: Now that's what I have thought and forgot to mention in my question. Thank you so much. 

EDIT: Is it possible to use local notification when the app is already terminated?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use push notification as well. Works when terminated.

Comment: @JackyW Thanks. So a push notification coming from a server, and not a local notification. I'm reading articles right now about sending local notifications even if the app is terminated already.

Comment: @prettyitgirl.com No problem. Check out firebase by google. Powerful tool for various purposes. I'm using Firebase for push notification, not complicated to set up, works flawlessly. Good luck! :D